# jquery prepend does not work in IE

Tags: jquery

I have the below code which does not work in IE 8 but works fine in firefox. Please advise

```
var thePop = $("<div class='popup destroyMeOnClose'><script language='javascript'></script></div>");
thePop.prepend("<div class='close'><a>x</a></div>"); <--this line throws error in IE8
```

funny enough if i remove the "`<script language='javascript'></script>`" from the code it works in IE as well. why?

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked for me, all i did was render the complete html first and then prepend, previously i was doing the prepend before render

Answer (score 1):

Javascript parses `</script>` literal without taking into consideration that you're declaring it inside a string. You should use

```
var thePop = $("<div class='popup destroyMeOnClose'><script language='javascript'><\/script></div>");
```

or

```
var thePop = $("<div class='popup destroyMeOnClose'><script language='javascript'></sc" + "ript></div>");
```

Comment: i get "unexpected call to methor or property access"